# Access report - Preview selected pages

Tags: ms-access

If one condition I've specified returns true I want to open my report in preview mode and the report should show all the pages minus the last one. i.e. if the total number of pages is 10, preview only pages from 1 to 9.

I was thing about tweaking [this code](https://forums.windowssecrets.com/showthread.php/155411-Access-2007-Print-only-1st-page-of-report?s=eea0746a23321048779954191793d817&p=912255&viewfull=1#post912255), it works however it goes directly to the printer dialog box and bypasses the preview step completely.

Do you know how I can specify which pages to show in preview mode?

Comment: What is on last page, just report footer? Code can set Visible property of report sections. Page will still likely generate, just be blank. Aside  from that, don't think any way to prevent pages displaying.

Comment: @june7 No, there's a page break and then there's a full page after that. I need to hide all the content after the page break (it will always fit in one page).